# What is the C# equivalent of java ResultSet for MySQL Server?

Tags: c#, mysql

I am new on learning C#, the resultSet class in java is very easy to use (at least for me) to recover table data from selects, i have been searching about how to read data from a select in C# but i dont know if they are the more convenient methods.

What is the best way of obtaining table data from MySQL in C#?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try to keep it short... I have not quite used java (just basic knowledge) nor do I know the resultSet class but I can tell you how to obtain table data from MySQL in c#...
I'd explain using NHIBERNATE as the framework of choice.

In connecting between databases and applications, the standard is to use a suitable ORM (Object Relational Mapper). The purpose of which is to connect application domain classes (entities) with database tables. you can have a table given by the following below:-

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ShipmentRequest](
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Name] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [FirstName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
    [LastName] [nvarchar](max) NULL,
)
```

this sql table would translated into the following class

```
public class ShipmentRequest
{
   public virtual int Id {get; set;}
   public virtual string Name {get; set;}
   public virtual string FirstName {get; set;}
   public virtual string LastName {get; set;}
}
```

now we are clear with some fundamentals on ORM, next you will want to decide which ORM is best to connect c# to MySQL... the two most common ORM in c# are Entity Framework and NHibernate...the two work very similarly to the above explanation, you'd create the classes with the appropriate configuration to allow the database and tables be generated (or synced if the db exist already).

That been said I'd just explain one of the ORMs and that would be NHIBERNATE as stated earlier.

To get started, open up your visual studio (download and install if you don't have one). create a simple project or open up an existing project. click on an assembly/project, then go to dependencies/framework. Right-click on it and go to manage nuget packages. if you must know, Nuget package manager in c# is a third party framework repository where people can build standard c# libraries that can be download from visual studio, Nuget package manager allows for a well organized placement for third-party libraries as well as easy integration to c# projects (most often, in one click). you download NHiberate (search for it and click install).

You map the above class to the table you want like this:-

public class ShipmentRequestMap : ClassMap

{

```
   public ShipmentRequestMap()

   {

       Id(x => x.Id);

       Map(x => x.Name);

       Map(x => x.FirstName);

       Map(x => x.LastName);

       Table("ShipmentRequest");

   }
```

}

Your config file looks something like this

```
using System.IO;
using System.Reflection;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg;
using FluentNHibernate.Cfg.Db;
using NHibernate;
using NHibernate.Cfg;
using NHibernate.Dialect;
using NHibernate.Driver;
using NHibernate.Tool.hbm2ddl;

namespace YourApplication
{
    public class NHibernateConfig
    {
        private const string connStr = "Server=.;Port=4005;Database=yourdatabaseDB;Uid=yourusername;Pwd=yourpassword;";

        public static ISessionFactory CreateMySqlSessionFactory(){
           var config = new Configuration();

           config.DataBaseIntegration(x => {
               x.Driver<MySqlDataDriver>();
               x.ConnectionString = connStr;
               x.Dialect<MySQL5Dialect>();
           });
           var sessionFactory = Fluently.Configure(config)
                                        .Mappings(m => m.FluentMappings.AddFromAssembly(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly())).ExposeConfiguration(cfg => new SchemaExport(cfg)

            .Create(false, false)).BuildSessionFactory();

           return sessionFactory;

        }                      
    }   
}
```

The database is now connected to the application. all that remain is to write your, IRepository, BaseRepository, and other services...

your repository will be something like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;

namespace IRepository.Data {
    public interface IRepository<T> {
        void Create(T entity);
        void Update(T entity);
        void Delete(T entity);
        void Copy(T source, T target);
        void Flush();

        T Get(int id);
        T Get(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);

        IQueryable<T> Table { get; }

        int Count(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        IEnumerable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
        IEnumerable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Action<Orderable<T>> order);
        IEnumerable<T> Fetch(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate, Action<Orderable<T>> order, int skip, int count);
    }
}
```

So this is how database connection to application in c# is done, you might also consider using entity framework if you prefer. happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

U can use SqlDataAdapter to fill DataTable or DataSet in C#.